# error: Cannot read property 'classList' of null (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
```

I am not really sure what am I doing wrong in manipulating DOM element. I tried to get element by id class and name but I still get errors
see my script:

```
  onDropDown(): void {
    document.querySelector("#dropdown").classList.toggle("show")
  }
```

and my html:

```
<aside class="right">
    <ul id="dropdown">
        <li><a routerLink="/" class="active">about me</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/contact">contact</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/education">education</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/work">work</a></li>
    </ul>

    <i (click)="onDropDown()" class="fas fa-bars"></i>

</aside>
```

error: Object is possibly 'null'.

Comment: Why not to use ngClass instead? Put some flag in function `onDropDown`, for example `this.isListVisible = !this.isListVisible`, and then on `ul` element add `ngClass="{ 'show': isListVisible }`. More about ngClass here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: you should try and avoid `document.querySelector` if  possible and use angular features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of native JS, is not the best way to get an element, you can just add #dropdown to your html element, and get it by @ViewChild in your TS file. We call this "Template variables".
IN HTML : <ul #dropdown>.......
IN TS :
@ViewChild('someVar') el:ElementRef;

Now el is a DOM Element, you can toggle class if you want

Comment: Actually, it's still DOM manipulation with native JS as you're still using the classList function later on. Angular allows class changes without the need to use functions outside of Angular scope, in this case - `ngClass`. `ngClass` is better solution, because it is simple and most correct way of using Angular for class manipulations.